# Wpf - Can't grab frames from a video?

Tags: wpf, emgucv

I'm trying to grab all frames from my video in WPF and using emguCV 3.0.

But the Retrive(frame, 0) always returns frame which has null Bitmap?

I guess that the problem occurs in the Capture(string filename) but I don't know why it is.

Can any one explain to me and give me some solutions?
thanks.

Here is my code

```
Capture _capture;
    private void btnCut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                _capture = new Capture(@"H:\VisualC\HK5\LT Win\ForTesting\TestCutVideo\bin\Debug\Hay.mp4");
                _capture.Start();
                //bool isReading = true;
                while (/*isReading*/_capture.Grab())
                {
                    Mat frame = new Mat();
                    _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
                    if (frame != null)
                    {
                        imageArray.Add(frame);
                    }

                }

                //to Cut list of frames from video.
                int start = 1, end = 10;
                start = start * (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
                end = end * (int)_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps);
                VideoWriter vw = new VideoWriter("test.mp4", 15, new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400), true);
                for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
                {
                    vw.Write(imageArray[i]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

"while" should be called somewhere else, otherwise you only did one time. Try

```
Mat frame = new Mat();//Global
private void btnCut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _capture.ImageGrabbed += ImageGrabbedEvent;
    _capture.Start();
}
void ImageGrabbedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
}
```

record

```
//new VideoWriter
VideoWriter vw = new VideoWriter("test.avi", 15, 400, 400, true);

//maybe a new Thread that include while
    while(isRunning){
        if (frame != null)
        {
             Image<Bgr, Byte> videoframe = frame.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
             vw.WriteFrame(videoframe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've edited my code so that I can grab all frames. But now my problems is writing a video from those frames. Although I've written 250 frames, My result video can't be opened and has only 6KB size with 0 frames. Can you help me?

Comment: I couldn't record "mp4". Make sure your frame size match the one you set in VideoWriter